# Как залить docker образ на удаленный сервер? Как деплоить приложение?

Tags: docker

Вопрос мне самому кажется нубским, но ответа на него я пока получить не могу...

Ок, я запустил докер-контейнер локально, постучался к нему, получил ожидаемый ответ и испытал оргазм.

Как мне теперь доставить образ (что из этого правильней доставлять?) на удаленный сервер?

Чтобы было понятней, что и откуда я скачал, прикладываю свой dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY dist /server
EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: контейнеры: export/import, образы: save/load. но вообще я подозреваю, что образ вы не с нуля создавали, а скачали откуда-то. тогда скачайте его оттуда же и на второй машине.

Comment: @alexander barakin Ваш комментарий слишком лаконичный - я в нем ничего не понял. Если Вас не затруднит, опишите более развернуто пожалуйста. По поводу того, что образ я откуда-то скачал - ну часть образа наверняка откуда-то скачалась. Чтобы было яснее, сейчас приложу свой docker файл.

Comment: ну вот и выполните этот dockerfile на второй машине (точно так же, как сделали это на первой). с этим проблемы?

Comment: @alexander barakin кажется я понял куда вы клоните. спасибо)

Comment: Как альтернативный вариант, можно залить Ваш образ в registry (команда docker push) и скачать на сервере (команда docker pull)

Answer (score 1):

> доставить образ

Вначале нужно сбилдить и залить в registry (dockerhub или [ваше приватное хранилище](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)).
После руками можно скачать из него и запустить контейнер.

> Деплой

Изучить docker-compose, docker swarm, он проще k8s. На удаленном сервере развернуть docker swarm.

`docker swarm init`

Изучить [traefik reverse-proxy](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/). Из коробки получите установку и автообновление ssl. Плюс динамическую генерацию endpoints.

Советую его деплоить как отдельный stack as traefik (сеть proxy).

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.stack.yml traefik`

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: "$REGISTRY/${TRAEFIK_SERVICE}:${TRAEFIK_SERVICE__VERSION}"
    networks:
      - proxy
    deploy:
      mode: global
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 3s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik_acme:/etc/traefik/acme:rw
networks:
  proxy:
volumes:
  traefik_acme:
```

Все web application подключаются к нему по сети (external - traefik_proxy).

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  app:
    networks:
      - proxy
    healthcheck:
      test: 'nc -z localhost 80 > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      labels:
        traefik.enable: 'true'
        traefik.docker.network: traefik_proxy
        traefik.backend: frontend
        traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method: drr
        traefik.frontend.entryPoints.http.redirect: https
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host: app.example.com"
        traefik.port: '80'
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
```

Попробовать развернуть [traefik and private registry](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/docker-swarm-example). После развернуть web приложение.