# docker-compose: нет связи между контейнерами

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

У меня есть три микросервиса, которые я запускаю в докере.

Dockerfile каждого из них выглядят так.
Фронтенд:

```
FROM node:alpine
LABEL maintainer="2262288@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /usr/app/front
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Бэкенд 1:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="2262288@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8099
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/auth-0.0.3.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} digital.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/digital.jar"]
```

Бэкенд 2:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="2262288@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/sender-0.0.1.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} sender.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/sender.jar"]
```

По замыслу, Фронтенд общается с бэкендом 1, а тот периодически выдаёт задания Бэкенду 2, отправляя ему REST-запросы.

Потом я всё это публикую на хабе и собираю на внешнем сервере с выделенным IP в docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    image: account/front:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:3000
  back:
    image: account/back:0.0.3
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8099:8099
  message:
    image: account/message:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
```

При запуске docker-compose сервисы запускаются на портах:

```
message_1_e8eb3b2d2477 | 2019-09-24 09:34:00.882  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''

back_1_1982cc6e57f7 | 2019-09-24 09:34:07.403  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8099 (http) with context path ''
```

Как мы видим, оба бэкенда стартовали каждый на своём порту.

Далее я перехожу на страницу фронта и через него вызываю метод, в результате которого бэкенд1 вызовет бэкенд2 (message). Бэкенд1 делает запрос в message и получает ответ:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

То есть, запросы с back в message не приходят.

Делаем то же самое через Postman с локальной машины. Всё работает, сервер отвечает. Пути идентичны, но даже если бы я ошибся с запросом, был бы ответ.

В связи с этим, уважаемые коллеги, у меня вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Какой URL прописан в back? Для внутренней связи между приложениями в контейнерах в качесте хоста надо указывать имя сервиса. т.е в вашем случае `http://message:8082/...`

Answer (score 0):

> То есть, запросы с back в message не приходят.

Скорее всего проблема в файерволе. Снаружи блокируется, а локально нет.

> В связи с этим, уважаемые коллеги, у меня вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Во-первых, **не используешь reverse-proxy**. К примеру [traefik](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup/tree/master/services/traefik) (let's encrypt из коробки). Снаружи только 80 и 443 порты.

Во-вторых, **не используешь bridge networks**. Приложения лучше изолировать. Пускай общаются только через bridge. Снаружи все через reverse-proxy.

Во-третьих, **используешь docker-compose в staging / production среде.**

> собираю на внешнем сервере

Приложение **собирается на машине разработчика или CI и заливается в docker-registry** (dockerhub или на свой). Во время деплоя скачивается с registry.

DNS нотация docker-compose и docker-swarm отличается. `http://message:8082/` соотвествует docker-swarm. C docker-compose будет так - `http://message.project_path_default:8082`. Можно менять `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=test` и указать свою сеть `net`, тогда будет `http://message.test_net:8082`.

Попробуй [docker-swarm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921751/251778), добавляешь [docker-compose.swarm.yml](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/7607408ce748fc2f605a7ca1d7fbb40dfea3f6f0/docker-compose.swarm.yml) c его спецификой. Более подробно можно ознакомиться в моем [проекте автоматизации деплоя с ansible](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup).

В-четвертых, **не используешь [multi-stage build](https://blog.xebialabs.com/2017/05/25/multi-stage-docker-image-build-for-java-applications/)**

> ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/sender-0.0.1.jar
>
> ADD ${JAR_FILE} sender.jar